# Perform trim-like operation on a normal HDD?

Tags: storage, disk-utility, trim

Is there a way to perform the same thing on a HDD as Trim does on a SSD. 
I assume the used sectors should be rewritten with 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overwriting ("wiping") sectors marked as free is not what TRIM does. Read the Wikipedia article to learn what TRIM does: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM_%28SSD_command%29 You don't need to and can't TRIM a conventional harddrive.

If you want to overwrite empty sectors for security reasons you can use a tool like `sfill` on GNU/Linux (on Debian it is in the secure-delete package) or Ccleaner on MS Windows.